# Add extra label - 120% on y - axis in python?

Tags: python, data-visualization

[image]

How do I add 120% on my y axis as a label ?

Comment: Do you mean to expend the y axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which visualization module you are using but usually pyplot and other have the `plt.ylim(inf,sup)` function that changes the limits on the axis. You can also create an axis object and edit its limits like `ax.set_ylim(inf,sup)`.
If you want to add the label at 120% you have to edit the Tick Labels of the axis you have created.